# swift tabBarController selectedIndex not working

Tags: swift, uitabbarcontroller

How do you call tab index manually on a tabbar controller with more than 5 view controllers?

I am trying to call a tab index manually but it does not seem to be working. I have a tabview controller with 6 view controllers. I am using selectedIndex to call a specific tab. On an iPhone, this works fine for the first 4 tabs, but not for tabs 5 and 6. It works fine on an iPad.

This is what I am using:

```
let getViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "tabBar") as! UITabBarController
getViewController.selectedIndex = 5
self.navigationController?.present(getViewController, animated: true)
```

This results in the tabbar showing the first tab, not the intended 6th tab. Since it is working fine on an iPad, I assume the "More" tab is making the tabindex to not work

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Call `selectedViewController` instead of `selectedIndex`.

Comment: how did you use it exactly?

Answer (score 0):

It is likely because the view has not yet been loaded, so the IBOutlets and sub view controllers have not been set yet.

You could try calling `getViewController.loadViewIfNeeded()` before you set the selectedIndex. Or create a class that extends `UITabBarController` and in `viewDidLoad` set the required `selectedIndex` in there.

I have been using a `UITabBarController` today and used `selectedIndex`without any issues.

Comment: thanks! I was able to get it working with selectedViewController